# How can I allow a user to copy/paste text from a collapsible set in jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I have a collapsible set in jquery mobile that looks like this:

```
<div data-role="collapsible-set">
    <div data-role="collapsible">
        <h1>
            <span style="font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold; white-space: pre-wrap;" id="title">This is a really long book title</span><br>
            <span style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: normal;" id="author">This is the Author of the book</span>
            <span style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: normal; font-style: italic;" id="year">Yr</span>
        </h1>
        <div>Info inside set</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want my users to be able to highlight the text in the heading of each list item (what's in my h1 tag) similar to how the text in the collapsible section can be highlighted. That way the text can be copied/pasted.

I realize that the whole list items are essentially buttons. But would it be possible to make only the plus icon the button? That way the text in my header can be highlighted?

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k9ocb8sg/) of my collapsible-set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if their is a Jquery way to enable copy on the button or if there are any CSS hacks that will enable copy also.

Anyway, this method makes the button width small. The headers are above the collapsible, and that should be ok even if the collapsible s are dynamic. Some other css to move everything a bit so they align ok. It can be improved a bit, but as you can see its certainly doable.

**Demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/oq2a2r2o/

**CSS**

```
.ui-collapsible-inset .ui-collapsible-heading .ui-btn
{width:15px !important;
margin-top: -45px;
position: fixed;}

.ui-btn-icon-left { padding-left: 0 !important; }

.nextto { margin-left:50px; margin-bottom:5px
```

}

**Result**

[image]